# Adding the ability to run a script as a service to a Docker image

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a Docker image and want to include the ability the run a script as a service (systemd).

My base image is centos7 .
Is there a way to add the ability to run some python scripts in the background as a service

Comment: No need for systemd. Docker is designed to run as a service whatever the entry point is.

Comment: Was going to say the same thing as @ElmoVanKielmo, however are you suggesting that you want to run other scripts alongside your main application? Say cleanup scripts?

Comment: @ ElmoVanKielmo
I have some python scripts I want to run in the background as a service.  Hope this make my query clearer

Comment: @ leeman24 
Some supporting scripts for my application

Comment: General practice is to run one process per container.  Do _not_ try to run systemd in a container; it wants to manage a very large number of things, many of which the host is already managing.

Comment: Also as a general rule, commands like `service` and `systemctl` just don't work in Docker.  There are ways to make them work, but it's better to run the single thing the container is doing as a foreground process.

Comment: @David Maze
Thanks for the advice... I am trying to dockerize an application that we've using for awhile.  So based what you wrote, how can I get my scripts to work without systemctl?

Comment: See https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ . I really recommend supervisord, for the purpose of running multiple process inside a container.You basically need to config all tour services in a conf file and supervisord will manage them.